# Difference between catkin_init_workspace inside src vs catkin_make

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, I guess this is more of a conceptual question, what are the differences (or even benefits) of running:

```
catkin_init_workspace
```

inside the workspace/src directory vs running:

```
catkin_make
```

In the root of the workspace. According to me they are equal and I've always preferred to just create the workspace and src inside and then run **catkin_make** directly, but I haven't found out if there are big differences from one to the other.

Thanks for your time!

**EDIT**:
I've seen that `catkin_init_workspace` will:

" Actually, it creates a symbolic link to a system-wide CMakeLists.txt file."

According to the [Programming Robots with ROS](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024736.do) book.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274584/difference-between-catkin_init_workspace-inside-src-vs-catkin_make/) by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 700 on 2017-10-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`catkin_make` is performing the actual build. It will implicitly initialize the workspace for you.

`catkin_init_workspace` only creates the `CMakeLists.txt` file in the root of the source space (see https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/c0b6ca5d67adb13745c4899868cdee17c9118f5e/python/catkin/init_workspace.py#L57). You only need to use it if you later want to call something like `cmake` and `make` manually. So usually you never have to invoke `catkin_init_workspace` yourself.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2017-10-30**:
Thanks for the quick answer, so `catkin_make` will also generate the `CMakeLists.txt` right? So just running `catkin_make` will also allow me to use `cmake` and `make`?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-10-30**:
Yes, that is correct.